# Sequelize - Wrong sql request generated using include, with a basic example

Tags: join, sequelize.js, include, associations

I have a problem with sequelize V6 and a very basic example of one-to-many association.

### My associations :

```
    this.coupleTable.hasMany(this.userTable);
    this.userTable.belongsTo(this.coupleTable);
```

### What is working :

1. The foreign key "actionId" is successfully created in the userTable, and it references the id of coupleTable.

[image]

2. I can retrieve one user and his couple with two requests, using getCouple().

```
    const user = await db.userTable.findByPk(userId);
    const couple = await user?.getCouple();
```

### What is not working

--> I cannot retrieve one user and his couple with an **eager** fetch, i.e one request.

```
const userWithCouple = await db.userTable.findByPk(userId, { include: db.coupleTable });
```

The sql request is generated with the wrong JOIN clause, strictly the opposite of what I expect.

Instead of having :

> LEFT OUTER JOIN user.coupleId = couple.id

We have :

> LEFT OUTER JOIN user.id = couple.coupleId

However, my example seems to fit the doc perfectly : [doc-eagerLoading-V6](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#basic-example)

**What am I doing wrong here ?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time to find out that **the problem was only occurring in the jest tests**.

And the responsible is here : `jest.resetModules();`

-> If you encounter a similar issue with a weird behaviour of sequelize with jest, just **do not reset the modules**, or find an alternative method to reset only what you want.

## Why ?

I do not know. It could be a bug, or perhaps not. Maybe someone reading this will have the answer.

In my opinion, it is a bug. Because everything works fine (eager fetch one -> many with hasMany, associations, BelongsToGetAssociation, etc.), but not the eager fetch many -> one (belongsTo).